# How to choose which minSdkVersion?

Tags: android

I developed an application and I put it on Google Play, but the thing is that sometimes, some people fail to install it and i don't know the reason. 

However, i'm not sure if the reason is because my minSdkVersion is set to "8".
I'm using Android 2.2 API.

Is it ok to set the minSdkVersion = "1" ? and what are the disadvantages of putting it as "1" instead of "8". How should I choose it? That makes me confused because in the same time I want everyone to install my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is very little benefit from using API 1 as the minimum SDK. Check out Android's [Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of active devices. It shows that 3.1% of users still have API 7 or below, 0.4% for API 6 below.

You will also find great difficulty, if it is even possible, to recreate many of the modern features in API 1... even the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) only works on API 4+.

**In short**, it is unlikely that your minimum SDK version is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Only set the minSdkVersion to the lowest you have tested on.  If you use features that are specific to API level 8 (or higher), and don't specifically check for their existence, then your users on lower versions won't be able to run anyway.

Running lint can also smoke out bugs from lower versions.

This number will only filter out users on the market.  They will get a message saying the app isn't compatibile with their version.  It sounds to me like the problems you are having are that users are *failing* to install.  I don't believe changing the minSdkVersion will help you there.  This is most likely to do with bugs in the Android Market version they are using.